# Flutter ios app not building with razorpay plugin

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, dart, razorpay

I was unable to build my flutter app in ios as I was getting these error, again and again, everything is working well for android.I get these error after using razorpay plugin in my app for integrating payment gateway.

> Error output from Xcode build:
> ↳

- BUILD FAILED *

Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:44:1: error: unknown attribute '_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers'
@_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers @objc public class PluginPaymentModel : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:51:41: error: unknown attribute '_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers'
@objc @_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers public class Otpelf : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:51:7: error: unknown attribute '_inheritsConvenienceInitializers'
@objc @_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers public class Otpelf : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:59:35: error: unknown attribute '_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers'
@_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers @objc final public class RazorpayCheckout : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:59:1: error: unknown attribute '_inheritsConvenienceInitializers'
@_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers @objc final public class RazorpayCheckout : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/develop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.2.2/ios/Classes/RazorpayDelegate.swift:2:8: error: failed to load module 'Razorpay'
import Razorpay
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:44:1: error: unknown attribute '_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers'
@_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers @objc public class PluginPaymentModel : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:51:41: error: unknown attribute '_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers'
@objc @_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers public class Otpelf : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:51:7: error: unknown attribute '_inheritsConvenienceInitializers'
@objc @_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers public class Otpelf : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:59:35: error: unknown attribute '_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers'
@_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers @objc final public class RazorpayCheckout : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface:59:1: error: unknown attribute '_inheritsConvenienceInitializers'
@_inheritsConvenienceInitializers @_hasMissingDesignatedInitializers @objc final public class RazorpayCheckout : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
^
/Users/ganpat/develop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.2.2/ios/Classes/RazorpayDelegate.swift:2:8: error: failed to load module 'Razorpay'
import Razorpay
^
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
/Users/ganpat/develop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-4.4.0/ios/Classes/strategies/NotificationPermissionStrategy.m:71:5: warning: 'UIRemoteNotificationType' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions for user notifications and registerForRemoteNotifications for receiving remote notifications instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
UIRemoteNotificationType type = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/permission_handler/permission_handler-prefix.pch:2:
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:69:32: note: 'UIRemoteNotificationType' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIRemoteNotificationType) {
^
/Users/ganpat/develop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-4.4.0/ios/Classes/strategies/NotificationPermissionStrategy.m:71:72: warning: 'enabledRemoteNotificationTypes' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use -[UIApplication isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] and UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:] to retrieve user-enabled remote notification and user notification settings [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
UIRemoteNotificationType type = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/ganpat/Desktop/Flutter_Apps_Projects_2021/wsflutter/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/permission_handler/permission_handler-prefix.pch:2:
/Users/ganpat/Desktop/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:229:1: note: 'enabledRemoteNotificationTypes' has been explicitly marked deprecated here

- (UIRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes API_DEPRECATED("Use -[UIApplication isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] and UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:] to retrieve user-enabled remote notification and user notification settings", ios(3.0, 8.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
  ^
  2 warnings generated.
  note: Using new build system
  note: Planning build
  note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max

Comment: Which swift version you are using

Comment: 5.3 but have tried with 5.0